# Get first instance of every row using column value as key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have 2 dataframes

```
>>> new
     OrderID            TimeStamp  ErrorCode Duration       ResponseType  \
1    3000000  1488948188556444675          0      IOC  NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
4    3000001  1488948658787811582          1      IOC  NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
8    3000003  1488949109654294973          1      IOC  NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
11   3000004  1488949129882309795          0      IOC  NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
14   3000005  1488949156441102746          1      IOC  NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM
```

and

```
>>> new2
     OrderID            TimeStamp  ErrorCode Duration       ResponseType  \
1    3000000  1488948188556444675          0      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM   
4    3000000  1488948658787811582          1      IOC  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM   
8    3000000  1488949109654294973          1      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM   
11   3000001  1488949129882309795          0      IOC  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM   
11   3000001  1488949129882309795          0      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM
14   3000003  1488949156441102746          1      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM  
44   3000004  1488949156441102746          1      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM  
34   3000005  1488949156441102746          1      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM   
24   3000009  1488949156441102746          1      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM
```

I want  to map new.orderID to new2.orderID, such that only keys in new are considered and first instance of that key in new is given back.

eg. OrderID 3000000 has 3 responses but only 1st should be considered.

op

```
>>> new
     OrderID            TimeStamp  ErrorCode Duration       ResponseType  \
1    3000000  1488948188556444675          0      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM   
4    3000001  1488948658787811582          1      IOC  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM   
8    3000003  1488949109654294973          1      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM   
11   3000004  1488949129882309795          0      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM   
14   3000005  1488949156441102746          1      IOC  TRADE_CONFIRM
```

Comment: Tell us what have you tried.